# Fast, cross-platform timer?

Tags: time, garbage-collection, timer, d

I'm looking to improve the D garbage collector by adding some heuristics to avoid garbage collection runs that are unlikely to result in significant freeing.  One heuristic I'd like to add is that GC should not be run more than once per X amount of time (maybe once per second or so).  To do this I need a timer with the following properties:

1. It must be able to grab the correct time with minimal overhead.  Calling `core.stdc.time` takes an amount of time roughly equivalent to a small memory allocation, so it's not a good option.
2. Ideally, should be cross-platform (both OS and CPU), for maintenance simplicity.
3. Super high resolution isn't terribly important.  If the times are accurate to maybe 1/4 of a second, that's good enough.
4. Must work in a multithreaded/multi-CPU context.  The x86 `rdtsc` instruction won't work.

EDIT:  The plain old C function `clock()` seems fast enough.  However, here overflow is a problem.  On 32-bit Windows and Linux, `clock_t` is defined as a 32-bit signed integer.  When it overflows, does it become negative, or does the `clock()` function use extra logic to make it wrap to zero instead?  If it wraps to zero, then this will do the trick.  If it wraps to negative (which also represents error codes, etc.) then it isn't going to work.

Edit # 2:  I tried the heuristic out anyhow, using `clock()` and ignoring the overflow issue, just as a test.  It performs so poorly that it's not worth further investigation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ideally, should be cross-platform (both OS and CPU), for maintenance simplicity.

I think that brings you down to whatever you can find in the standard C library.

Perhaps [clock](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/clock/)?

Answer (score 3):

Well, my first suggestion would be to use core.time or std.datetime. It does have a `StopWatch`. Is it not fast enough? It uses whatever the standard monotonic clock is for the system, and I would *hope* that that would be fast enough. It's certainly the highest precision that you're going to get (though how the high precision affects speed, I don't know). However, if it isn't fast enough, I'm not at all sure that your other options are any better. It's generally the case that you either get second precision or high precision. There isn't much in between. And with high precision, it's generally at least microsecond precision with the question being how much beyond that it goes. 1/4 second precision isn't exactly normal.

Cybershadow's suggestion of [clock](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/clock/) may be do the trick - certainly it's your only option which is standard C as far as I know - but it may or may not be fast enough.

Aside from [clock](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/clock/)... On Linux, if you want a non-monotonic way to get the time with higher precision than one second, I believe that [gettimeofday](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gettimeofday.html) is your only real option, but I don't know how fast it is. On Windows, the best non-monotonic solution that I'm aware of is [getSystemTimeAsFiletime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but Windows has [several time functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725473%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) that you could play around with.

You can look at std.datetime's `Clock.currStdTime` to see how to do either of those (though it uses `clock_gettime` on Posix if it's available, which is what core.time uses - albeit with a different clock - so you probably want the `else` portion of that function for Linux if `StopWatch` is too slow for you). However, it does convert to hnsecs from midnight January 1st, 1 A.D., so depending on what you do with the number, you'll want to skip that portion of the calculation.

Comment: I don't want to alarm anyone, but I've read a few articles about QueryPerformanceCounter problems on Windows (StopWatch uses it in its implementation).


Edit: I keep forgetting to press shift+enter and I end up posting.. Sorry. Here's a few articles:


http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895980

http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=106

https://jongampark.wordpress.com/2008/04/19/weirdness-of-the-high-resolution-counter-ie-queryperformancecounter/

Comment: I'll take a look at those links later, but as far as I know, `QueryPerformanceCounter` works just fine for timing stuff. It's trying to use it for getting the current time which is a big problem. If you try and do that, your results drift, which is obviously bad.